# user enters 10 numbers into an array how would I write code to find that number and output what position it is in the array?

Tags: java

Very new to arrays in Java but the problem I was given to solve is this:

> "In your main method, prompt the user to enter ten numbers and store
>   them in an array. Write a method called find that returns the position
>   of the first occurrence of a particular number in the array. If the
>   number is not in the list, your method should return ‐1. From main,
>   prompt the user to enter a number, call the find method, and display
>   the result to the user from main. If the method returned ‐1, inform
>   the user that the number was not in the list. Do not interact with the
>   user from within the findmethod. The signature of your method must be:
>   public static int find(int[] arr, int thingToFind)"

Output example:

```
 Enter ten numbers: 18 14 82 17 2 14 6 2 18 4
 What number would you like me to find? 2
 2 first occurs in the 5th place in the list.

 Enter ten numbers: 4 19 0 41 ­2 ­7 7 14 41 100
 What number would you like me to find? 99
 99 is not in the list.
```

I know I need a loop to be in the find method but not sure which one, I'm thinking a for loop but not sure how to implement it. Here is my code as of now, yes I know I'm missing a lot, and it's just the start of it. Not sure where to go from here.

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter 10 numbers ");
    int n = in.nextInt();
    int arr[] = new int[n];
  }

   public static int find(int[] arr, int thingToFind){

     }

   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will return the index of thingToFind, or -1 if thingToFind is not found.

```
 public static int find(int[] arr, int thingToFind){
  int i;
  for(i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++){
    if(arr[i] == thingToFind){
      return i;
    }
  }
  return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
void find(int[]arr, int tofind){
   for (int i: arr){
        if (arr[i]==toFind){
           System.out.println(tofind+" first occurs at "+i+"th place in the array")
        return
   System.out.println("not found")
```

}
}

Answer (score 2):

You have a way to go yet. You know that you have ten numbers so you can write

```
int arr[] = new int[10];
```

before you read in any number.
Also, you will need a loop to to read in your numbers. You could just write

```
arr[0] = in.nextInt();
arr[1] = in.nextInt();
arr[2] = in.nextInt();
```

and so on, but you can do better than that, right?

Answer (score 1):

You will need a for loop as you said, because you can use the index (normally `int i = 0`) to acces the elements of the array which you are iterating over. In each loop, check if the element at i is the number you are looking for. If yes, return i. After the loop, return -1, since you will only reach this part if you didn't find the number.

Some things you may need:

- `arr.length` is the size of your array
- `arr[i]` is the element at the position i

Answer (score 1):

I think your method should look something like this

```
  public static int find(int[] arr, int thingToFind){


        for(int i = 0;i<arr.length;i++){
            if(arr[i]==thingToFind){
                return i+1;
            }
        }
        return -1;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**I prefer avoiding one line function!** 
Returns the index of the value within the array, returns -1 if not found or null array input[1]

```
public static int find(int[] arr, int tofind) {
     return ArrayUtils.indexOf(arr, tofind);
}
```

[1] http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html#indexOf-int:A-int-